# How do you import public key in C#?

Tags: c#, client-server, rsa

I can create both the server's and client's asymmetric keys and then I export them and attempt to exchange them. My problem, and I have not been able to find a solution to this, is that I want to import the server's public key to the client program. That comes in as a byte[], but I need to be able to use that as a RSAParameters to be able to encrypt data to go to the server. How do I convert the byte[] to an RSAParameters type?

```
private void secureButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clientRSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] clientPublicKey = clientRSA.ExportCspBlob(false);

            stm.Write(clientPublicKey, 0, clientPublicKey.Length);
            stm.Read(serverPublicKey, 0, serverPublicKey.Length);
        }
```

I know that this is not a "secure" way of doing this, due to being vulnerable to MITM, but I am running up against a hard school deadline and this is a brickwall that I need to get by before I can proceed any further.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never done the blob, but what I usually do is use `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXMLString()` to export into XML. I then put that XML in the resource in my app and then in the future use `RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXMLString()` to load those parameters back in. You don't have secure a public key. It's public.

Comment: Thanks Pete, this worked great and got me by the brick wall. First time messing with the RSACryptoServiceProvider, so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll go ahead and make this the answer, then:

I've never done the blob, but what I usually do is use `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXMLString()` to export into XML. I then put that XML in the resource in my app and then in the future use `RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXMLString()` to load the key parameters back in.

You don't have to secure a public key. It's public

Answer (score 3):

To convert byte[] public key to RSAParameters, you can use the same class, **RSACryptoServiceProvider**;

```
byte[] clientPublicKey = ...
var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
provider.ImportCspBlob(clientPublicKey);
var parameters = provider.ExportParameters(false);
```

Comment: I am getting error: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Bad Version of provider.'